# Eclipse "unhandled event loop exception" when trying to create AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, loops, exception, unhandled

I had AVD created from a while ago and everything was working fine, but I wanted to make a new one and found out that this happens. When I click "ok" to try and create the AVD nothing happens and the error pops up "unhandled event loop exception". No matter what options I choose for the AVD I can't create it.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the AVD Manager by click the **AVD Manager.exe** under your android-sdk/tools folder. Or start it using command line:

1. Go to your android-sdk/tools folder;
2. Type the command:

> android avd
>   
>   This works for me.